# php mysql Select data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table. My table data type is SET.

my table

```
+------+
| col  |
+------+
| a,d  |
| a,c  |
| a,d  |
| a,e  |
| a,c  |
+------+
```

MY code

```
select * from tbl1 where col = c
```

If I want to select how many match with c

then my query return zero but It will be 2.

Comment: You should rethink your database design, databases are supposed to store [atomic values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Make it two columns and this would be trivial.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization is the only way to go

Comment: While I agree that this is not good database design, mySQL supports the data type so we should know how to use it.  Here's a link to a function that may help. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 1):

mySQL has some embeded functions to work with this data type.

[find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in this case would seem to fit the bill..

```
Select * from tbl1 where find_in_Set('c',col) > 0;
```

Though I'm for data normalization MrLore discusses as well.

Comment: This is great for small datasets but brutally slow for any that are non-trivial in size.

Comment: No arguments here.  The OP choose to use set, I assume they understand the limitations and risks.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use "matching the characters" by using mysql LIKE

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  as total_matches  from tbl1 
WHERE col LIKE '%c%';
```